# Print function in a class not updating when boolean is updated

Tags: c++, function, class, printing, boolean

So I have a program for a class that Im writing that is all done except for the print function. The input function is correct and the boolean value will update in the input function but when i try to transfer to the print function it always prints (-) and if the user enters 'Y' then it is suppose to bypass the (-) and just print out the fraction. If anyone has anyway to get it to work, I feel like ive tried everything.

Edit: The print function works when i print out just the two fractions in main which are f1 and f2 but the problem is coming when passing the positive into the print function i believe.

```
class fraction

{
    private:
        int numerator;
        int denom;
        bool positive;

    public:
        void inputFrac();
        void printFrac();

        fraction fracMult(fraction& b);
        fraction fracDiv(fraction& b);
        fraction fracAdd(fraction& b);
        fraction fracSub(fraction& b);
};

 void fraction::printFrac()
{
 if (positive=true)
    {
        cout << "-" << numerator << " / " << denom;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "+" << numerator << " / " << denom;
    }
}
void fraction::inputFrac()
{    
    char tempchar1;
    fraction tempchar;

    cout<<"Please input the numerator ";
    cin>>numerator;
    cout<< "Please input the denominator ";
    cin>>denom;
    cout<<"Is the fraction positive? (Y or N) ";
    cin>>tempchar1;

    if((tempchar1=='Y'))
    {
        positive=true;

    }
    else
    {
        positive=false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning within your `if` statement.
Change:

```
 if (positive=true)
```

to:

```
 if (positive==true)
```

Comment: Or even: `if (positive)`

Comment: And this is a good example, that you better get accustomed to writing`if`s, `while`s, and other conditional statements in a form of `if ([value] == variable)`. Because even when you make a mistake, and write `=` instead of `==`, you get a compile error. Granted, this wouldn't help if you are comparing 2 non-const variables, but at least it helps to shave off some bugs like these.

Comment: I added this and the fraction prints out as whatever the first sign is, so it continues to print out with the (-) even if I put Y for both of the fractions when it asks if its positive Edit: The print function works, i just tried it with f1 and f2 and it printed them out with the correct signs but for some reason when i go to print them out when they pass the functions it doesn't work

Comment: For one thing, the `if` statement is actually backwards... it's doing: if (positive) cout << "-"

Answer (score 0):

In your printFrac function, you have `if (positive=true)`. This is incorrect, for what you are doing. You should instead have  `if (positive) {/*stuff*/}`.

Comment: I added this and the fraction prints out as whatever the first sign is, so it continues to print out with the (-) even if I put Y for both of the fractions when it asks if its positive